# Sending Google Docs content in HTML format via email using GMail API

Tags: python, google-drive-api, gmail-api

We are using Google Docs as a Email template resource in one of our application.
We have n number of templates for different different emails.

When the mail is to be sent, what we do is:

- Get the html content of that particular template using Google Drive api.
- Send that html content in Email using GMail api.

Now the problem is, the some of html attributes changes automatically when person receives email eg. the bold/italics/underline, fonts are replaced by the default fonts of Google Mail.

I have created a sample email template [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_3qpUE0sSzJoLgHvZUbNJi35LJT-AvipZDM0Z6zPg9U/edit). You can try playing with it.

Have anyone came across such problem ?
Is there any other alternative to accomplish ?

Comment: Does the recipient also use Gmail? Each email-client (Outlook, Notes, Apple Mail, etc) parse the HTML in very different ways.

Comment: Yeah. Recipient also use GMail.